# Why does this queue empty out, while I operate on a copy of it?

Tags: python, function

I have a function (Python 3):

```
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(3)

def printqueue(u):
    while not u.empty():
        print(u.get())

printqueue(q)

print(q.empty())
```

Why is `q` empty at the end while I operated on `u`? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You did not operate on a copy.  Repeat any tutorial on passing a mutable sequence object to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do not operate on a copy of it, but instead the exact same object.

You can easily check this with the built-in [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def printqueue(u):
    print(id(u))

print(id(q))
printqueue(q)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 140230517913872
> 140230517913872
> ```